# which are mandatory activity of start() method in java thread class

Tags: java, multithreading

I know that why you have to call start method in thread but i want to know that what are other mandatory activity done in start method except calling run method..

Comment: Compling the code and run the JVM. ;)

Comment: @MouseEvent i want to know that thread name, default priority is set in start()  method.........is this mandatory activity done in start() method

Comment: You should not extend `Thread`, instead implement `Runnable` and use `new Thread(yourRunnableHere).start()`. And if for some reason you really want to extend Thread, then don't override `start()`, but override `run()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking what the `start()` method does?

Basically ...

1. It creates a thread stack for the thread (typically with a ["red-zone"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_zone_(computing)) to trap stack overflows)
2. It creates / starts the native thread, passing it the `Thread` object.
3. It returns to the caller.
4. Meanwhile, the newly created / started native thread calls back to the JVM to run the `run()` method.

(A bunch of other important things happen in the instantiation of the Java `Thread` object.  Before `start()` is called.)

If you want more detail, please refer to the OpenJDK source code.